# Running programme to monitor file infiteley

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to run infinitely a program that monitors a logfile and updates to the database the errors that have occured and keeping track of a max number of occurances for some error so to send an email if one error is occuring too many times. I managed to do the programme that listens and updates appropriately and sends the email but I don't know how I am gonna be able to start off the programm to run infinitely as it will be monitoring a live system. On the other hand I have a web UI that displays the info updated by the monitoring programme, in other words I don't want the updating programme to stop running even when I my web UI is closed in the browser, behind the scenes I want updating programme to continue to run. I want to separate them so they run independent of each other. I am using Servlets and JSPs for my front end. I was thinking of starting the updating programme in my servlet but I am thinking when it is closed the updating programme will stop run which is what I am trying to avoid. Any kind of advice is highly appreciated, any tool available that allows running a programme infinetely and only stops when server is down and thanks in advance.

> ```
> NB: I wanted to use log4j to append errors to database to allow me easier 
> updating but the system wasn't designed to accommodate my requirements so
> I have no choice but to use this approach.
> ```

Comment: You should implement your own logging listener, I guess, which delegates to the "real" logger for file access

Comment: Hi fge, thanks for your respond, I would like to implement that but since I am junior ,the manager doesn't want me to play much around the implementation of the real system, I can only be fully allowed to do that after three months, but I shall implement my separate logging listener and converse with him and hear what he says. Thank you.

Comment: The thing is, monitoring the log file is equally hard if not harder. Junior or not, do the correct thing and surprise your manager ;)

Comment: Hahaha, thanks for the advice, I shall do it and stand bold, I like that. Thanks once again :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Web UI displays information retrieved from the database and if you want to separate out the web UI from the monitoring program, I would suggest keeping a separate native Java process running that constantly monitors the log file and updates the database. The database will be used as a communication medium between the two Web UI and the Java process.

That way the Java process will remain independent of the Web UI and can run indefinitely.

Think it this way -

```
1. Java process updates the database as it monitors the log file
2. The Web UI reading from database whenever it is up.
```

The Java process can probably also communicate with Web UI service to provide some heart beat to acknowledge that it's up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi JtheRocker, thank you for your reply, yes the system Web UI data depends on the data in database only to display data exactly what you assume like you said in your first statement. I shall try doing what you suggest and I shall report back to you if I am going off on a tangent, thank you.